# transaction log grows despite recovery=simple. SHRINKFILE does not release space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log, shrink

I have this script that restores a DB, sets recovery=simple, trims some tables & shrinks files:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [ABC] FROM DISK (....)
ALTER DATABASE [ABC] SET RECOVERY simple
go
exec [ABC]..trim
```

"trim" stored proc is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE trim   
AS
TRUNCATE table A
TRUNCATE table B
(...)
DELETE TOP 1000 FROM C where date < @somedate
DELETE TOP 1000 FROM D where date < @somedate
(...)
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'ABC_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'ABC_data' , 0)
```

Note - each of the "DELETE TOP 1000 FROM D where" is done in a loop until no more rows to delete. This to keep each transaction small.

When I run all of this script manually, step by step all is well - transaction log is kept small, SHRINKFILE truncates the log table to 1KB

When this is executed all as one script, all in one run, this is what happens:

- transaction logs keeps growing (as if recovery=full)
- SHRINKFILE does not truncate the log, long remains 99% empty but huge

Any hints what could be going wrong? Do I need a "GO" placed somewhere?

Comment: If you query [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), what does `log_reuse_wait_desc` show? You may need to add a `CHECKPOINT` into the mix.

Comment: it is set to "NOTHING"

Comment: You can't have GO since it is a stored proc, and even if you make int a non proc, GO shouldn't matter. . I'd throw in a few WAITFOR commands and play with the delay.

Comment: hmm... thanks for the hint, will try. any ideas where to put the wait for? I am really puzzled by this ... should I do wait for after setting the DB to simple recovery ?

Comment: Not sure if this was what Tibor was getting at, but I'd try adding a `WAITFOR DELAY` command in the loop, just to slow down the rate at which you're creating transactions. *Potentially* you are outpacing the rate at which the log is reused for new transactions, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Yep, that is what my thought was. Give slq server time to breathe between each delete. You can also throw in  a CHECKPOINT command after the pause.

Comment: Thank you for the insights! However, while this may explain the log file growth, how come SHRINKFILE does not work?

Comment: You said that shrinkfile doesn't work for the log, specifically. You would have to collect information and troubleshoot this (if you think it is a good idea to shrink the log in the first place). Here's a starter: https://karaszi.com/large-transaction-log-file